# How do I improve the performance of this PHP hash calculator?

Tags: php, hash, scrypt

I want to generate scrypt hashes in PHP. We're using it to link with a system that only suppots scrypt, so unfortunately we can't just choose another algorithm that PHP comes with native support for. We also need to run this on servers we don't necessarily have root access to and may not have the ability to install PHP extensions on. By default, the iteration count is set at 260000.

I've tried my best to set up a pure PHP implementation of scrypt, using PHP's built in `hash_pbkdf2` function along with the following function to calculate the scrypt salt. I call this function with `array_walk($salt_calc, 'gen_salt', [262144, 8]);`.

```
<?php
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');

function gen_salt(&$x, $key = '', $y = [262144, 8]){
    //$start_time = microtime(true);
    $v = [];
    for ($i = 0; $i < $y[0] * 2; $i++) {
        if($i >= $y[0]) $x ^= $v[unpack('V', substr($x, -64))[1] % $y[0]]; else $v[$i] = $x;
        $b = substr($x, -64);
        $out = ['', ''];
        for ($n = 0; $n < 2*$y[1]; $n++) {
            $b32 = [];
            for ($j = 0; $j < 16; $j++)
                $b32[] = unpack("V", substr($b ^ substr($x, 64 * $n, 64), $j * 4, 4))[1];
            
            $salsa = $b32;
            for ($si = 0; $si < 8; $si += 2) {
                $a = ($salsa[ 0] + $salsa[12]) & 0xffffffff;
                $salsa[ 4] ^= ($a << 7) | ($a >> 25);
                $a = ($salsa[ 4] + $salsa[ 0]) & 0xffffffff;
                $salsa[ 8] ^= ($a << 9) | ($a >> 23);
                $a = ($salsa[ 8] + $salsa[ 4]) & 0xffffffff;
                $salsa[12] ^= ($a << 13) | ($a >> 19);
                $a = ($salsa[12] + $salsa[ 8]) & 0xffffffff;
                $salsa[ 0] ^= ($a << 18) | ($a >> 14);
                $a = ($salsa[ 5] + $salsa[ 1]) & 0xffffffff;
                $salsa[ 9] ^= ($a << 7) | ($a >> 25);
                $a = ($salsa[ 9] + $salsa[ 5]) & 0xffffffff;
                $salsa[13] ^= ($a << 9) | ($a >> 23);
                $a = ($salsa[13] + $salsa[ 9]) & 0xffffffff;
                $salsa[ 1] ^= ($a << 13) | ($a >> 19);
                $a = ($salsa[ 1] + $salsa[13]) & 0xffffffff;
                $salsa[ 5] ^= ($a << 18) | ($a >> 14);
                $a = ($salsa[10] + $salsa[ 6]) & 0xffffffff;
                $salsa[14] ^= ($a << 7) | ($a >> 25);
                $a = ($salsa[14] + $salsa[10]) & 0xffffffff;
                $salsa[ 2] ^= ($a << 9) | ($a >> 23);
                $a = ($salsa[ 2] + $salsa[14]) & 0xffffffff;
                $salsa[ 6] ^= ($a << 13) | ($a >> 19);
                $a = ($salsa[ 6] + $salsa[ 2]) & 0xffffffff;
                $salsa[10] ^= ($a << 18) | ($a >> 14);
                $a = ($salsa[15] + $salsa[11]) & 0xffffffff;
                $salsa[ 3] ^= ($a << 7) | ($a >> 25);
                $a = ($salsa[ 3] + $salsa[15]) & 0xffffffff;
                $salsa[ 7] ^= ($a << 9) | ($a >> 23);
                $a = ($salsa[ 7] + $salsa[ 3]) & 0xffffffff;
                $salsa[11] ^= ($a << 13) | ($a >> 19);
                $a = ($salsa[11] + $salsa[ 7]) & 0xffffffff;
                $salsa[15] ^= ($a << 18) | ($a >> 14);
                $a = ($salsa[ 0] + $salsa[ 3]) & 0xffffffff;
                $salsa[ 1] ^= ($a << 7) | ($a >> 25);
                $a = ($salsa[ 1] + $salsa[ 0]) & 0xffffffff;
                $salsa[ 2] ^= ($a << 9) | ($a >> 23);
                $a = ($salsa[ 2] + $salsa[ 1]) & 0xffffffff;
                $salsa[ 3] ^= ($a << 13) | ($a >> 19);
                $a = ($salsa[ 3] + $salsa[ 2]) & 0xffffffff;
                $salsa[ 0] ^= ($a << 18) | ($a >> 14);
                $a = ($salsa[ 5] + $salsa[ 4]) & 0xffffffff;
                $salsa[ 6] ^= ($a << 7) | ($a >> 25);
                $a = ($salsa[ 6] + $salsa[ 5]) & 0xffffffff;
                $salsa[ 7] ^= ($a << 9) | ($a >> 23);
                $a = ($salsa[ 7] + $salsa[ 6]) & 0xffffffff;
                $salsa[ 4] ^= ($a << 13) | ($a >> 19);
                $a = ($salsa[ 4] + $salsa[ 7]) & 0xffffffff;
                $salsa[ 5] ^= ($a << 18) | ($a >> 14);
                $a = ($salsa[10] + $salsa[ 9]) & 0xffffffff;
                $salsa[11] ^= ($a << 7) | ($a >> 25);
                $a = ($salsa[11] + $salsa[10]) & 0xffffffff;
                $salsa[ 8] ^= ($a << 9) | ($a >> 23);
                $a = ($salsa[ 8] + $salsa[11]) & 0xffffffff;
                $salsa[ 9] ^= ($a << 13) | ($a >> 19);
                $a = ($salsa[ 9] + $salsa[ 8]) & 0xffffffff;
                $salsa[10] ^= ($a << 18) | ($a >> 14);
                $a = ($salsa[15] + $salsa[14]) & 0xffffffff;
                $salsa[12] ^= ($a << 7) | ($a >> 25);
                $a = ($salsa[12] + $salsa[15]) & 0xffffffff;
                $salsa[13] ^= ($a << 9) | ($a >> 23);
                $a = ($salsa[13] + $salsa[12]) & 0xffffffff;
                $salsa[14] ^= ($a << 13) | ($a >> 19);
                $a = ($salsa[14] + $salsa[13]) & 0xffffffff;
                $salsa[15] ^= ($a << 18) | ($a >> 14);
            }
            $b = pack("V*", ...(array_map(function($in, $salsa_in){ return ($in + $salsa_in) & 0xffffffff; }, $b32, $salsa)));
            $out[$n % 2] .= $b;
        }
        $x = implode($out);
    }
    //print_r((microtime(true)-$start_time).' sec.');
}

// example use
$password = 'some_password';
$salt = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32);
$n = 262144;
$r = 8;
$p = 1;
$length = 32;

$salt_calc = str_split(hash_pbkdf2('sha256', $password, $salt, 1, $p * 128 * $r, true), 128 * $r);
array_walk($salt_calc, 'gen_salt', [$n, $r]); //wait 2 minutes here
echo hash_pbkdf2('sha256', $password, implode($salt_calc), 1, $length*2, false);
```

This function works, in that it gives me the correct hash, and doesn't require installing extensions; the problem is it takes 2 minutes to generate a single hash and uses a *lot* of memory doing so. I've tried simplifying and optimizing it by hand, although without much success... So I'm looking for suggestions on how to accomplish this.

Comment: 1. "uses a lot of memory" yes, that is the point of scrypt. 2. "takes 2 minutes" I'd test this myself, but you haven't posted any way to properly invoke this code, and it's not obvious from what you've posted. Though if you're doing tight loops over data structures you're basically running into one of PHP's worst use cases which is why there are compiled extensions for something like this.

Comment: @Sammitch I added an example of how that function is used to the bottom of that code paste. The memory use isn't really an issue, main issue is how slow it is